# How to get select box options from GetCustomFields() method of jira

Tags: api, soap, jira

I was curious if anyone else had an idea how to get a select box options of the custom field  in JIRA using soap api, if you have have custom field id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference select list values by their id. To get id go to **Custom Field configuration -> Edit Options**. Hover over the option's '**Edit**' operation (or click on Edit) and check link address. It will be something like 'secure/admin/EditCustomFieldOptions!edit.jspa?fieldConfigId=10480&selectedValue=**10030**'

**selectedValue** is the id of select list option.